# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"' when I use 'class' on php

Tags: php, class

```
class MailAuthGen{
    var $mail='test@mail.com';
    var $findUid = "SELECT uid from 'accounts' where email='$mail'";
    function abc() {
        echo $this->findUid;
    }
}
```

when I load this page, the page shows

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"'

Even

```
$findUid = "SELECT uid from 'accounts' where email='".$mail."'";
```

didn't work.

But, when I didn't use 'class', it executed well.

What's the problem?

Comment: Please show the full error message (notably the line number)

Comment: Wow it took at least 3 reads for me to actually understand what you were trying to say :\

Comment: Why do you use PHP4 OOP style?

Comment: the parse error is the full error of my code. That's why I was confused.

Comment: oh I omitted the error line. sorry.

Comment: the point was why i can't declare $findUid like that.

Comment: @Hoon Check comments under the answer, it is becuase expressions cannot be evaluated in the classes variable delcarations like: `public $o = new Class()` so you must do this sort of the stuff in the constructor or within a dedicated function, tbh I thikn it would have been better in the `abc` function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error is with this line. You can't evaluate any variables when declaring properties.

```
var $findUid = "SELECT uid from 'accounts' where email='$mail'";
//                              You can't do this ------^
```

A common workaround is something like:

```
var $findUid = "SELECT uid from 'accounts' where email='%s'";
```

Where you can interpolate the value later.

Comment: Good catch. What a bizarrely unhelpful error message given what the problem actually is.

Comment: To be fair, I copy/pasted the code and ran a lint-check to get the line number. Leaving it out isn't cool.

Comment: What is interesting is this didn't work either: `$findUid = "SELECT uid from 'accounts' where email='".$mail."'";` which has no escaping problems so not sure if this would work since this answer is based upon that the variable cannot be placed in the string there...

Comment: @Sammaye The issue is that you cannot use *the result of an expression* to initialise a property in an object, only a static value can be used. If you wanted to do something like your example, you'd have to do it in the constructor.